# Rewriting a query - tricky JOIN task

Tags: mysql, join

This is my old SQL:

```
SELECT so.samplelist_id
   FROM sales_flat_order sfo
   JOIN sales_flat_order_address sfoa
     ON sfo.entity_id = sfoa.parent_id
   JOIN samplelist_order AS so
     ON Concat(Lower(Trim(sfoa.postcode)), Lower(Trim(sfoa.lastname))) =
        Concat(Lower(Trim(so.postcode)), Lower(Trim(so.lastname)))
```

As you can see, it compares strings (bad performance, I know) from `2 tables`, `sales_flat_order_address` and `samplelist_order`. That works. My task now is to rewrite that query, so that it does not use `samplelist_order` any longer, but `sales_flat_order_adress` as well.

The question is, how should one table (`sales_flat_order_address`) compare data with itself? Is that possible at all? Is there a trick how to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: can you share your query explain result?

Comment: It's not clear in what way you would want to compare this table with itself.. although doing so is of course completely possible. Whats the result you're looking for?

Comment: what you want in output result?

Comment: Folks, read the code - he's joining sales_flat_order_address & samplelist_order on post_code & last_name concat

Comment: @jmadsen, yes it's clear what he's currently doing, but I see no way to know what he expects the result of his new query to be. Obviously you can't do a self join on that same condition.

Comment: it's not a self-join - they are two different tables. he just doesn't have an fk set up properly

Comment: @jmadsen I really don't understand what question you're answering... a foreign key is a constraint, it makes no difference to the result of a query. He specifically says he needs to remove the join to `samplelist_order`.

Answer (score -1):

The best answer - IMHO - write a script to set up a normal fk relationship & run that in your application.

If you can't do that, create an extra field on each with the concatenated fields & index that